# Is there a command line script I can use to check if servers have SQL Server 2008 DMO installed?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, sql-server-2008, command-line-interface

SQL Server 2008 does not install DMO by default. Is there a function or script I can use from the command prompt to check remote servers to see if DMO has already been installed? We were using a registry key check but thought that might not be the best option. Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean SMO (DMO was replaced by SMO in SQL 2005).

You can do this as a quick and dirty test within Powershell:

```
PS C:\> [Reflection.Assembply]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo")
```

If SMO is registered it'll come back with some info on where it found the SMO dll and what version it is.

```
GAC     Version          Location
---     -------          --------
True    v2.0.50727       C:\.........
```

You could also use this VBS script if you don't want to do it in Powershell:

```
Dim sqlServer
set sqlServer = CreateObject("Microsoft.SQLServer.Management.SMO.Server")
set sqlServer = nothing
```

If it returns a runtime error `"ActiveX component can't create object: 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.Server'"` then SMO not installed (or at least not registered).

Comment: Sorry, I did not want SMO. DMO installation is required for a bug in SCOM 2007.